# Cannot alignright text on canvas when orientation to vertical

Tags: delphi, winapi

I am using the WinAPI **DrawText** to write to the canvas within a Rectangle.  I have to write text horizontally and vertically.  Using the **uFormat** constant to set how the text is aligned.
I cannot get it to align vertical text to the top of the rectangle. see image

[image]

This is the code I am using to draw the text

```
  procedure SetOrientation(pIndex: Integer);
  var j: Integer;
  begin
    f := 0;
    j := fPinCount div 4;
    if pindex < j then begin
      fBuffer.Canvas.font.orientation := 0 ;
      f := DT_RIGHT
     end else
     if pIndex < 2 * j then begin
       fBuffer.Canvas.font.Orientation := 900 ;
       f := DT_TOP
      end else
      if pIndex < 3 * j then begin
        fBuffer.Canvas.font.orientation := 0;
        f := DT_LEFT
      end else begin
      fBuffer.Canvas.font.Orientation := 900;
        f := DT_LEFT;
    f := f or DT_SINGLELINE or DT_NOCLIP;
  end;

    SetOrientation(i);
    DrawText(FBuffer.Canvas.Handle, s, Length(s), PinDscRects[i], f);
    fBuffer.Canvas.Font.Orientation := 0;
```

I have tried all values of uFormat but none will justify the vertical text.  Can you suggest an alternative method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface) is a very old graphics API, and sometimes this is quite noticeable. One could argue that this is one of those situations.

However, working around this limitation isn't difficult at all. For instance, you can do

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
const
  S = 'Nargles are cute!';
begin
  Canvas.Font.Orientation := 900;
  var R := ClientRect;
  OffsetRect(R, 0, Canvas.TextWidth(S));
  DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(S), S.Length, R, DT_SINGLELINE or DT_NOCLIP);
end;
```

or (since I think the `DT_NOCLIP` part is a bit ugly)

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
const
  S = 'Nargles are cute!';
begin
  Canvas.Font.Orientation := 900;
  TextOut(Canvas.Handle, 0, Canvas.TextWidth(S), PChar(S), S.Length);
end;
```

As you see, I simply translate the vertical spatial coordinate(s) I pass to the text-drawing function by the logical [width](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCustomCanvas.TextWidth) of the text in pixels.

Comment: Now aligning better using the TextOut API Call once I had worked out where the starting point should be.